# Oracle (ORA-02270) : no matching unique or primary key for that column list

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Trasy_srodki_transportu(
  ID_Trasy Integer NOT NULL,
  ID_pojazdu Integer NOT NULL
) 
/
CREATE TABLE Trasy(
  ID_Trasy Integer NOT NULL,
  Linia Varchar2(4 ) NOT NULL,
  Data_rozpoczecia_kursowania Date NOT NULL,
  Data_zakonczenia_kursowania Date,
  ID_Pracownika Integer NOT NULL
)
```

Now i want to add foreign key to Trasy_srodki_transportu referencing to Trasy table:

```
ALTER TABLE Trasy_srodki_transportu ADD CONSTRAINT Trasa_jest_wykorzystywana FOREIGN KEY (ID_Trasy) REFERENCES Trasy (ID_Trasy)
/
```

and this throws Oracle (ORA-02270) : no matching unique or primary key for this column-list error. Any suggestions how to fix this?[Data modeler view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Zvxv.png)

Comment: A foreign key forces that all values exist in the referenced table. Have you checked this point?

Comment: Do [any of the existing questions discussing this same error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22no+matching+unique+or+primary+key+for+this+column-list%22) help you at all?

Answer (score 2):

A foreign key needs to reference a key on the related table, but it's not the case in your example. Change the definition of the second table by adding a `PRIMARY KEY` constraint in it, as in:

```
CREATE TABLE Trasy (
  ID_Trasy Integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  Linia Varchar2(4 ) NOT NULL,
  Data_rozpoczecia_kursowania Date NOT NULL,
  Data_zakonczenia_kursowania Date,
  ID_Pracownika Integer NOT NULL
)
```

Alternatively, you can create a unique constraint on it, that can also serve as a key. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE Trasy (
  ID_Trasy Integer NOT NULL,
  Linia Varchar2(4 ) NOT NULL,
  Data_rozpoczecia_kursowania Date NOT NULL,
  Data_zakonczenia_kursowania Date,
  ID_Pracownika Integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT uq_idtrasy UNIQUE (ID_Trasy)
)
```